# snappy-tools installation error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-core

When i try to install snappy tools i get the following errors:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/beta; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get install snappy-tools bzr


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
snappy-tools : Depends: ubuntu-device-flash but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
ric@ric-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash snappy-tools bzr
[sudo] password for ric: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-device-flash : Depends: click-ubuntu-policy but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ric@ric-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash snappy-tools bzr click-ubuntu-policy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package click-ubuntu-policy is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'click-ubuntu-policy' has no installation candidate
ric@ric-ubuntu:~$
```

@Jan

Answer (score 1):

With `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/beta` you added a new repository to your apt-sources.

`sudo apt-get update` updated the package lists, including the one from the PPA you just added.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrades your packages to the newest ones available.

Finally, with `sudo apt-get install snappy-tools bzr` you try to install the packages `snappy-tools` and `bzr`. The installation of `snappy-tools` fails because that package depends on another package called `ubuntu-device-flash` but that's not goint to be installed.

Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash snappy-tools bzr` and report back.

#### Edit

`click-ubuntu-policy` isn't available in 14.04, only in newer releases: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=click-ubuntu-policy

This means that you have a mixed 14.04 / 14.10 system...

Comment: nope didn't work :(

Comment: click-ubuntu-policyhttp://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=click-ubuntu-policy

Comment: It worked from [here][1]


  [1]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-ubuntu-com/+bug/1447733

Comment: you should change `beta` to `tools`

Comment: As `beta` is explicitly mentioned in the question i cater for that in my response...

Comment: yup changing beta to tools worked , thanks. ( i think you should mention it in main answer)